# How to import ontology from URL to Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I want to import an ontology to Jena from a specific URL (this one: http://purl.org/spar/fabio). The OWL code is found here: http://eelst.cs.unibo.it/apps/LODE/source?url=http://purl.org/spar/fabio. How can I do this?
And after importing this ontology, how can I refer to any of its classes in the code?

Comment: You'd simply use the [Model.read(String url)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read(java.lang.String)) method on your OntModel.

Comment: How can I refer to any of its classes after importing it?

Comment: [OntModel.getOntClass(String uri)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#getOntClass(java.lang.String)) with the URI of the class that you want, or you could iterate though them with [listClasses()](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#listClasses()).  This is all pretty clear in the Javadoc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered clearly in the documentation.  (See [What should one do if they have a question that the answer is already on google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372/225437).)

Comment: A lot of this is discussed in the [Jena Ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) tutorial, too.